# Add button only last children DIV

Tags: jquery

I can't find a solution on how to create code that will add an "Add" button only the last children of the DIV. Now my code works but if someone click not in last row then button "add" show in wronge place.

Below I'm sending code and link to sanbox where is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".data-services button.btn-success").click(function() {
    var ele = $(this).closest('.data-services').clone(true).addClass("cloned");
    $(this).closest('.data-services').after(ele);
    $(".data-services.cloned button").clone(true);
    $(this).addClass("noactive");
    $(".data-services.cloned button.btn-danger").removeClass("noactive");
  });

  //Remove services
  $(".data-services button.btn-danger").click(function() {
    if ($(".data-services").length) {
      $(this).parent().parent().prev().find("button.btn-success").removeClass("noactive");
    }
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row data-services">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="services-add">service </label>
    <select id="services-add" class="form-select" name="services_add[]">
      <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
      <option value="Hosting">Hosting</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="services-price-add">price</label>
    <select id="services-price-add" class="form-select" name="services_price_add[]">
      <option value="100">100</option>
      <option value="150">150</option>
      <option value="300">300</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger noactive"><i class="fa-solid fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Remove</button>
  </div><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".data-services.cloned button").clone(true);` returns the new clone. You need to assign this somewhere.